# Calling C++ file from MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a folder that implements the Shape Context descriptor, and it contains `.m` files and `.cpp` files. When some `.m` file calls a `.cpp` file, MATLAB yields: `??? Undefined function or method ‹The functions' name› for input arguments of type ‹double›.` although I have everything in path.

Am I need to install something special in order to make MATLAB recognize this file?

-Thanks

Comment: You need to compile the .cpp files into MEX files for matlab to see them.

Comment: You're not telling readers of this question everything you've told the readers of your other question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823192/undefined-function-matlab -- from which this one derives.  I suggest you delete the old question, which is now potentially misleading, and edit all the details into this one.

Comment: How should I do it? The folder has a file called "batch_mex.m" that includes "mex FileName.cpp" lines.. This is what you meant?

Comment: If you want help understanding what `batch_mex.m` does the (a) read it, (b) execute it and see what happens, then (c) ask for clarification of the parts you don't understand.  But do all this after you have read the documentation @ymn's answer links to.

Comment: I read the manual, the weird thing is that it works on one computer and doesn't work on the other, although I installed the same MATLAB version and I'm trying to run the same file.

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference, but the first computer is 32-bit and the second 64-bit (it works on the first)

Comment: That would make a difference.  A mex file compiled for one platform (combination of o/s, machine address size (ie 32- or 64-bit), compiler, Matlab version, ...) is not guaranteed to work for another platform. Look at the name of the compiled mex file.  I expect it to include either 32 or 64 in the suffix.

Comment: I'm working with "Microsoft SDK version 7.1" on the first computer and "lcc-win32" on the other.. Is there a 64-bit version that will solve the problem? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.
When running on a 64-bit operating system the matlab couldn't read the `.dll` files.
I entered `mex FileName.cpp` for all my `.cpp` file and it created `.mexw64` files that solved the problem.

Thanks everyone again.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this manual: [Create C/C++ and Fortran MEX-Files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating-c-c-and-fortran-programs-to-be-callable-from-matlab-mex-files.html)

Comment: I selected a compiler ('Microsoft SDK' version 7.1) and I followed the manual.. but I still get the same error.